# Want to seperate the integer part and fractional part of float number in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am Working on Converting the value of foot to inches where 1 foot = 12 inches. I am calculating the height of person in inches. ex. 5.11 a person of height 5 foots and 11 inches means total 71 inches. Is there any way in Python so i can separate the int part & float part of float number for further calculations ? any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @AndrewWalker: Except in this case, we have an XY problem where the OP should not have a number in the first place

Answer (score 27):

To get the integer part of a float use the built-in [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
>>>int(5.1)
5
```

To separate the float part subtract the float with the integer:

```
>>>5.1 - int(5.1)
0.1
```

Or you could get the modulus *(which is the float part)* of the float with 1:

```
>>> 5.1 % 1
0.09999999999999964 #use the round() function if you want 0.1
```

Comment: The `%` solution would not work with negative numbers (`-5.1 % 1 == 0.9000000000000004`).

Answer (score 5):

For you, `5.11` is *not a float*. If it were, then it would mean 5.11 feet, which is 61.32 inches.

`5.11` *is a string* containing two pieces of data and a separator - parse it like one! If you change the separator to the more conventional `'` (i.e. `5'11`), it becomes obvious it is not a single float:

```
raw = raw_input("Enter feet'inches")
feet, inches = map(int, raw.split("'", 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the divmod (function or operator), using as denominator (divisor) the number 1:

```
>>> divmod(5.11, 1)
(5.0, 0.11000000000000032)

>>> 5.11.__divmod__(1.)
(5.0, 0.11000000000000032)
```

Comment: You should never have to invoke `__divmod__` manually!

Comment: @Eric, I took a look but didn't find out... can you provide me a referece about why I should never invoke the magic function __divmod__ directly?

Comment: Would you ever do `myList.__len__()`?

Comment: @Eric, thanks! I know for a long time that isn't right to call a magic function directly, but sincerely, in my very humble opinion, it depends of the context, and I can't see a good reason to no call `__divmod__` directly for a float. The divmod function doesn't do nothing special, (differently from len that throws an exception for certain kinds of errors).

Comment: I guess my point is that seeing a `__method__` suggests "Something unusual is going on here". You're right though, it is sometimes ok - for example, it's the only way when using `super`: `super(MyClass, self).__divmod__(other)`

Comment: divmod is a little faster than subtracting the integer form, which is the currently popular answer